# How to completely clear the background color of UINavigationController while transition in progress on iOS7?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimation

Everything has `clearColor` background in my app.

I push those `transparent` `UIViewController`s to my transparent `UINavigationController`. It works but while transitioning, I see a `gray or some background color` until the transition is completed (until the push animation is completed). After that, background is correctly transparent. But both while pushing and popping that non-transparent background color (where I can't find a clue for that color) breaks the transition quality. It is visually very ugly.

How can I prevent that hidden color that affects transition?

**Update:** OK. This flickering thing (the hidden color that appears between transitioning) only happens on iOS7+. This problem does not occur on iOS 6+.

Comment: Hi Frankish, did you solve your problem? I'm having an annoying UILayoutContainer with gray background that is in front of my background and I can't get rid of it.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I couldn't, so I changed the design. Your problem seems like something different, why don't you create a new question with the details? (;

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your window background color,and during push, if your viewcontroller view is tansparent, it will appear behind,
 try to change it in your app delegate
 in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" set your window background color

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However I have an UIImageView behind everything. That is why I am trying to make other views transparent. :|